# Adding a custom view to UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UINavigationController` that when an event is triggered I need a custom `UIView` to appear just below the `NavigationBar`, but not obstruct the current `ViewController`. I also will need to make the `UIView` persistent as Controllers are popped/pushed.

```
 -----------------
|   Status Bar    |
 -----------------
|     Nav Bar     |
 -----------------
|   Custom View   |
 -----------------
|                 |
| View Controller |
|                 |
 -----------------
```

I'm currently having my `CustomView (UIView)` set up the frame like:

```
- (id)initWithNavigationController:(UINavigationController *)navController {
    self.navController = navController;
    return [self init];
}

- (id)init
{
    CGRect viewFrame = self.navController.view.frame;

    return [self initWithFrame:CGRectMake(viewFrame.origin.x,
                                      self.navController.navigationBar.frame.origin.y + self.navController.navigationBar.frame.size.height,
                                      viewFrame.size.width,
                                      40.0)];
}
```

Is this the way to go about this?

Comment: try this https://github.com/tursunovic/DMRNotificationView

Answer (score 0):

```
- (id)initWithNavigationController:(UINavigationController *)navController {
    CGRect viewFrame = navController.view.frame;

    if (self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(viewFrame.origin.x,
                                      navController.navigationBar.frame.origin.y + navController.navigationBar.frame.size.height,
                                      viewFrame.size.width,
                                      40.0)]){
       self.navController = navController;
      }
    return self;
   }
```

Then

```
CustomView* _myCustomView = [[CustomView alloc] initWithNavigationController:navigationController];
[navigationcontroller.view addSubview:_myCustomView];
```